# How to read a vector of data from text file with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, scanf

I'm trying to accomplish a relatively simple task of reading an ASCII data file into MATLAB. The file structure is given below:

```
(0,180)
[ 0 0.0174533 0.0349066 0.0523599 0.0698132 ... ]
```

While I'm able to read in the first line with `fscanf` I fail to read in the vector of float values with an `'%f'`:

```
A = fscanf(fid, '(%d,%d)\n[ %f ]').
```

I have figured out a solution to my problem. Two calls to `textscan` must be used instead of a single call to `fscanf`. More elegant solution is always welcome.

```
function [range, theta] = readTheta(fname)

  fid = fopen(fname, 'r');

  line1 = fgetl(fid);

  C = textscan(line1, '(%d,%d)\n');

  range = [ C{1}, C{2} ];

  line2 = fgetl(fid);

  line2 = regexprep(line2, {'[ ' ' ]'}, '');

  C = textscan(line2, '%f');

  theta = C{1};

  fclose(fid);

end
```

Comment: Is the length of the vector constant or dynamic?

Comment: It is dynamic. Actually, it is the second number in the parentheses (180) in the example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push `textscan` a lot harder than this. For example, consider the following parameters settings to textscan.

```
data = textscan(anyLine,'%f','delimiter','[]() ,','MultipleDelimsAsOne',true);
```

Now this command will work for either of the lines above.

```
anyLine= '(0,7)';
data = textscan(anyLine,'%f','delimiter','[]() ,','MultipleDelimsAsOne',true); 
disp(data{1});

anyLine= '[ 0 0.0174533 0.0349066 0.0523599 0.0698132 ]';
data = textscan(anyLine,'%f','delimiter','[]() ,','MultipleDelimsAsOne',true); 
disp(data{1});
```